# Use another class to print out user inputs from a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I am trying to make a simple chessboard that asks the user for coordinates on the Chessboard, for example a5 or h7. When the user answers this, the user is then prompted to enter a chess piece (at the moment this can be any string as I don't want to check if its a valid piece just yet) which then gets stored in that coordinate. Ideally in the future I would like to make it so when the user inputs "Done", then the program will stop, and the next class displays all the values of the array that the user has entered, so for example:

```
"Enter a coordinate: a5"
"Enter a piece: Lemon"
"Enter a coordinate: h8"
"Enter a piece: Queen"
"Enter a coordinate: Done"
>User is then prompted with, for example:
"You have entered Lemon at a5"
etc
```

This would be the ideal output, but any help would be appreciated. The code I have now is this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ChessBoard
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char rows = 'a';
        String spot;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] grid = new String [8][8];

        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++, rows++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < grid[i].length; col++);
            String input = null;              // will be changed to a valid position
            boolean validCoordinate = false;   // will be true if position is valid
            while ( ! validCoordinate) {
                System.out.println("Enter a coordinate (for example, a5): ");
                input = scanner.next();
                validCoordinate = input.matches("[a-g][1-8]");
            };
            // now we now that the input is valid
            int row = input.charAt(0) - 'a';
            int col = input.charAt(1) - '1';
            String temp = row + col + " - ";
            System.out.println("Insert your piece:");
            input = scanner.next();
            grid[row][col] = temp + input;
        }
        String getGrid() {
            return this.grid;
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
        }
    }

}
public class printArray
{
    System.out.println(getGrid() + "");
}
```

So what I have tried to do is return the array and then print it when the loop is finished, but I get compiler errors saying that ";" is expected after getGrid, and identifiers are expected in the "System.out.println(getGrid() + "");" line